# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE works in one cell and doesn't work in the next one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This one works

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_2Zuta6uQB2qZJ2JVCI3RyTm2iGP9WNQO31tVYwge8/edit#gid=1355684357", "F1:F50"), "ZOZNAM")
```

and this one doesn't

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oT0LkWeF_r5NyCExOxdIoC6816UgtF8TXeJnDFSUsZ8/edit#gid=656203186", "F1:F50"), "ZOZNAM")
```

The difference is only in the URL of the Gsheet.

Both of the sheets are in the same folder, both have the same owner (me), both are basically the same.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
After some poking around I found out the problem is that one document is shared only with a few specific people and the other one is shared "with everyone with the link".
And even tho I am the owner of both files this setting prevents me from counting the number of cells. Ridiculous.

If anyone has any ideas what can I check more or do, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the 3 sheets or a copy of them? I have tried to reproduce it and I have been able to import both. Also, what error is giving you?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the exact sheets, but I made a copy of them and redacted unnecessary info. They can be found here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/167fHEDlgyRRZh87tEqCGAYTKRaS1QgZO?usp=sharing

There is no error, it just shows 0.

Comment: On the sheets you shared I can see that both are with a count of 4 which is correct. There is no issue there that I can see, are you having different results?

Comment: Oh, they were 0s before, but they are both correct now. But in my main sheets there are 0s where there are supposed to be other counts. Looks like the formulas work then. Hm, but what might be the cause that they don't work in those other sheets? I'll have to investigate more.

Comment: Have you found differences between the sheets that may have made the formula to go wrong? Is there any different cell formatting on the sheets?